# How to build a web-site based jquery mobile and desktop version with different layout in one html file properly?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I'm studying building web-apps for smartphones.
In our final project we need to build an application based on jquery-mobile that uses only one 
HTML file, but it must have a different design on desktop screens.

We only learned the idea how to do it using media-queries,
leaving the actual jqmobile-css file attached and editing the classes and id's via media-queries for different sizes of screens.

This can be a really hard way to do it.is there a better one? 
Also how could i use different jquery files for both- a jquery-mobile site and desktop site, if i need to prevent user getting from page-1 that includes a form to page-2 if he doesn't filled out the form correctly, in jqmobile it would be done via ajax but in normal jquery all the pages in one HTML file would be loaded at once and i would need to know how i can make a navigation properly using this way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than style using media queries you can use JavaScript to detect your users screen size. 
This allows you to create .css files for both and dependent on the screen, the correct file 
will be allocated.

**See:** http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

As for your form, simple javascript validation will do the trick, being place inside script tags at the bottom of the body.

Comment: thanks! this would be a great way to make a page for user before he comes to desktop site if he visit from a tablet or smartphone and let him choose between Desktop site and mobile site.